# All three constructors of org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job are deprecated, what is the best way to construct a Job class?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, deprecated

All [three constructors of org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#Job%28%29)
are deprecated, is there a way to construct a Job class the non-deprecated way?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 @Deprecated should always include instructions what to do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ignore the deprecation warnings and stick with the 'mapred' package, not 'mapreduce'.

This JIRA [MAPREDUCE-1734](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1734) removed the deprecations for 0.20.3.

Comment: Thank you to figure it out. It can be seen from this article, [The Next Generation of Apache Hadoop MapReduce](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2011/02/mapreduce-nextgen/), that the API may have big changes in the future. So maybe whether a class is deprecated or not is not that important.

Comment: I searched the hadoop API document, and find a way to solve my problem. [Job.getInstance(Cluster cluster)](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/class-use/Job.html#org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce)

Comment: @icycandy: `Job.getInstance(Cluster cluster)` is also deprecated now. use `Job.getInstance(Configuration conf)` instead.