# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getInstance

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have installed Apache hadoop 2.5 in my mac. I am writing a simple word count program.  Since some constructors of Job is depreteated I am using this..

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
```

Everything works fine from Eclipse, but when I try this using command line (hadoop jar. ...)

I am getting this error.

NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getInstance

Is it a class path error ?  Is the class hadoop is referring is not the one I am using when running from eclipse ?  How to solve this issue ?

thanks !

Comment: i found same kind of question posted, probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400701/all-three-constructors-of-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-job-are-deprecated-what-i) shall help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems your CLASSPATH in eclipse and the one in system (or the one you're using while compiling) are different.
In eclipse, go to project > properties and check the library used there and use the same while using from commandline.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
```

have been taken placed by

```
Job job = new Job(conf);
```

this is my own views.