# Hadoop 2.6.0 super(conf) is deprected when extending Job Class

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

I am using some old code(hadoop 1.2.0) in which Job Class is extended by another and initialized by constructor. 
**Now using hadoop 2.6 libraries for same code** 
It is giving warning : **"The constructor Job(Configuration) is deprecated"**
If i remove it, warning again for constructor **"The constructor Job() is deprecated".**
Please Help !

```
package mapred.job;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClusterStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;


public class Optimizedjob extends Job {

    private List<String> inputs;

    private String output;

    private String jobName;

    private int reduceJobs;

    public Optimizedjob(Configuration conf, String input, String output,
            String jobName) throws IOException {
    //  super(conf);
    //  Job.getInstance(conf);
        this.inputs = new LinkedList<String>();
        this.inputs.add(input);
        this.output = output;
        this.jobName = jobName;
        reduceJobs = 0; // Initalizing to 0 means equal to number of maximum
                        // reducers
    }

    /**
     * Optimize based on current setting
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void setup() throws IOException {
        JobConf job_conf = new JobConf(conf);
        JobClient job_client = new JobClient(job_conf);
        ClusterStatus cluster_status = job_client.getClusterStatus();
        int reducer_capacity = cluster_status.getMaxReduceTasks();

        // IO format
        setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        // Input file/dir
        for (String input : inputs) {
                        System.err.println("                                    added [" + input + "]");
            TextInputFormat.addInputPath(this, new Path(input));
                }
        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(this, new Path(output));

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(output), conf);
        fs.delete(new Path(output), true);
        // CommonFileOperations.rmr(output);

        if (reduceJobs == 0)
            setNumReduceTasks(reducer_capacity);
        else
            setNumReduceTasks(reduceJobs);

        setJobName(jobName);
        setJarByClass(Optimizedjob.class);

    }

    public void addInput(String input) {
        inputs.add(input);
    }

    public void setReduceJobs(int reduceJobs) {
        this.reduceJobs = reduceJobs;
    }

    /**
     * Sets classes for mapper, reducer and combiner.
     * 
     * The reducer and combiner can be null, in which case there won't be reduce
     * or combine step.
     * 
     * @param mapperClass
     * @param reducerClass
     * @param combinerClass
     */
    public void setClasses(Class<? extends Mapper<?, ?, ?, ?>> mapperClass,
            Class<? extends Reducer<?, ?, ?, ?>> reducerClass,
            Class<? extends Reducer<?, ?, ?, ?>> combinerClass) {
        setMapperClass(mapperClass);
        if (reducerClass != null)
            setReducerClass(reducerClass);

        if (combinerClass != null)
            setCombinerClass(combinerClass);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the output format of map step. Usually it's Text, or IntWritable.
     * @param mapOutputKeyClass
     * @param mapOutputValueClass
     */
    public void setMapOutputClasses(Class<?> mapOutputKeyClass,
            Class<?> mapOutputValueClass) {
        setMapOutputKeyClass(mapOutputKeyClass);
        setMapOutputValueClass(mapOutputValueClass);
    }

    /**
     * Runs the job. 
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws InterruptedException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public void run() throws IOException, InterruptedException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        setup();

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.waitForCompletion(true);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(String.format("Runtime for Job %s: %d ms", jobName,
                end - start));

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [All three constructors of org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job are deprecated, what is the best way to construct a Job class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400701/all-three-constructors-of-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-job-are-deprecated-what-i)